# How to write a custom view in Djagno admin interface

Tags: django, django-admin

I am writing a Newsletter app. I have all the things I need to get it running depsite I don't how to put the button `Send E-mail` while user create newsletter and select the user and how to redirect to my view?

Where is this kind of thing explained in the documentation? How to achieve this.

Comment: please read the doc carefully, use google and tutorials to learn the basics

Answer (score 0):

This should help you get started: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-views-to-admin-sites

Also, see the official django tutorial here if you haven't already: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/